# Default tikz arrow style in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to change the axis arrow style used in `pgfplots`to the default one obtained in `tikz`using `->`, i. e.

[image: Default tikz arrow style]

I've done some research but can't seem to find a way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `axis line style={->}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=left,axis line style={->}]

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With OP's newly added code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[thick, smooth, no markers,
    xmin = -1.1, xmax = 1.1,
    ymin = -1.1, ymax = 1.1,
    axis lines = center,
    axis line style={->},              %% put here
    xlabel = $\rho_{S}$,
    ylabel = $\rho_{\tau}$
    ]
    \addplot+[name path = OBEN, samples = 1000, black, domain = -1:1]
    {min(1, 0.5+1.5*x)};
    \addplot+[name path = UNTEN, samples = 1200, black, domain= -1:1]
    {max(-1, -0.5+1.5*x)};
    \addplot[pattern = north west lines] fill between[of=OBEN and UNTEN];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user2249626: Put `axis line style={->},` after `axis lines=center`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In an isolated document it works, however in the main file I'm working on the arrows are not changing. I use the externalize feature. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @user2249626 Difficult to guess things. Somewhere you have that setting which reverses the effect. Please search.